# Etiquette for an incorrect Pull Request

Tags: github, pull-request, etiquette

I recently made a PR on GitHub to a repo of a tutorial since I thought one of the comments was incorrect; but I was mistaken.

One of the contributors commented asking how it was incorrect. What's the correct way to say "Oops, my bad. Everything was correct after all"?

Comment: Thanks for the points everyone made. I chose to write: "Oops, my bad. Everything was correct after all. Thanks for your time" and close the PR. A colleague suggested that it's better to end on a positive note instead of something like "Sorry/aplologies".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your suggested sentence is fine.

If you want, you can also

- thank the other person for spotting your mistake and
- explain *why* you were mistaken.

If you made the mistake, others might as well - after all, you mentioned that the repo is a tutorial, and tutorials are aimed at beginners. Maybe there's a way to improve the tutorial so that others won't make the same mistake you did?

> Oops, my bad. Everything was correct after all!
>
> I initially thought that foo needed to be initialized to avoid frobnicating the bar, but after reading your comment and re-reading the code I realized that  baz was explicitly designed to handle uninitialized foos. Thanks for spotting my mistake.

Comment: Excellent! It will even be helpful if this comment is not acted upon as even then it might be found by others with identical or similar thoughts in the issue history of the project.

Answer (score 23):

> Oops, my bad. Everything was correct after all.

seems absolutely fine to me. You could add "sorry for the distraction" or similar if you wanted to.

Answer (score 15):

To add to [Philip Kendall's answer](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/13186/327): After explaining and/or apologizing, don't leave the PR open. If you agree it's fundamentally redundant, close it yourself:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

"Oops, I was mistaken, sorry! Thanks for your time."